# Powershell script - Replace FilePath for all the URIs given in a Text file

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Power-Shell.

Given a text file with multiple file paths each separated by a New Line, I'm trying to replace the file path of each of these with a new path for the same file.

Example:
Input file :

```
C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared\log4net.dll
C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared\Aspose.dll
C:\Dependency\SL\UnStable\Crystal.dll
```

Output file :

```
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\log4net.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Aspone.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Crystal.dll
```

My attempt:

```
Get-ChildItem "*.txt" -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {

    foreach($line in Get-Content $_) {

        $currentPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($line)
        ($line) -replace $currentPath, '\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\' | Set-Content $line
    }
}
```

This is erring on the replace line.

Answer (score 0):

this uses `Split-Path` to get the file name. then it uses `Join-Path` to build the new full path. [*grin*]

```
$SourceFile = "$env:TEMP\Reddy-In.txt"
$DestFile = "$env:TEMP\Reddy-Out.txt"

# create a file to work with
#    remove this section when ready to use your own data
@'
C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared\log4net.dll
C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared\Aspose.dll
C:\Dependency\SL\UnStable\Crystal.dll
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $SourceFile

$Prefix = '\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release'

$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath $SourceFile
$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $FileName = Split-Path -Path $IS_Item -Leaf
    Join-Path -Path $Prefix -ChildPath $FileName
    }

# display on screen
$Results

# send to a text file
$Results |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $DestFile
```

screen output ...

```
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\log4net.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Aspose.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Crystal.dll
```

text file content ...

```
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\log4net.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Aspose.dll
\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\Crystal.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message I was getting was

```
The regular expression pattern C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared is not valid.
At C:\temp\StackOverflow.ps1:6 char:9
+         ($line) -replace $currentPath, '\\ServerName\websites$\Stable ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Project\SharedLib\Shared:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

This tells me that the string C:\Project\SharedLib is being treated as a [RegEx pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)- and we need to escape the operators. (That's why you'll often see backslashes doubled up- they are escaped.)

No need to remember what they are all- you can use [regex]::escape($currentPath) to do it for you.

```
Get-ChildItem "*.txt" -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {

    foreach($line in Get-Content $_) {

        $currentPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($line)
        ($line) -replace [regex]::escape($currentPath), '\\ServerName\websites$\Stable\Release\' | Set-Content $line
    }
}
```